# Getting, Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK: Failed parse during installPackageLI

Tags: android, android-source

I have build the email apk from aosp source code . When Iam installing the built apk on android nougat 7.1.2 phone, i am getting error

> Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK: Failed parse during
>   installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl478574931.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML
>   file line #30): Requires development platform R but this is a release
>   platform.]

the manifest file email app has this defined

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="24" android:minSdkVersion="11" />
```

Comment: Can you post your app.gradle file here?

Comment: My app does not have app.gradle , it is email stock aosp android app